# ¿Como almacenar los datos de un formulario y almacenarlos en un array y cuando se vuelva a enviar el formulario aparezca los de este y el anterior?

Tags: javascript, array, formularios, dom

Quiero enviar un formulario y cuando este se envie almacenar los datos en un array y cuando se vuelva a enviar que se almacenen el en array los datos enviados y los anteriores y asi sucesivamente cada vez que se envie el formulario siga almacenando la informacion en un array

```
introducir el código aquí

 <form action="#" id="form">
       <label>
           <input type="text" name="text">
       </label>
          <input type="submit" value="crear">
</form>  
<script>
const tranqui = document.getElementById(`form`)
tranqui.addEventListener(`submit`, e => {
    e.stopPropagation() 
    e.preventDefault()
    let a = e.target 
    let b = a.name.value 
    let array = []
    let c = null 
    c+= b 
    array.push(c)
   console.log(array)
    })
   </script>  

introducir el código aquí
```

Answer (score 0):

para almacenar la informacion de un formuario necesitas tener un script corriendo en el servidor (backend) en el lenguaje de tu preferencia (php, pearl, ruby, node, etc) que reciba esa informacion y la procese como tu requieras

De lo contrario cada vez que el cliente envie esa informacion se perdera en el limbo...

Comment: falso el esta pidiendo al momento de cargar los datos guardarlo en un array ... al menos leíste la pregunta???

Answer (score 0):

ocurre que la única forma de que esto ocurra seria saber como cargas el formulario.
si esto lo haces por `ajax` o xhr, etc, entonces una ves que tienes la respuesta `response` del servidor y una vez pintado el html/Contenido en el DOM; debes ejecutar un Método que te serialice el contenido del formulario antes de que el usuario Escriba:

```
Ejemplo del método:

function serialize (form) {
    if (!form || form.nodeName !== "FORM") {
            return;
    }
    var i, j, q = [];
    for (i = form.elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
        if (form.elements[i].name === "") {
            continue;
        }
        switch (form.elements[i].nodeName) {
            case 'INPUT':
                switch (form.elements[i].type) {
                    case 'text':
                    case 'tel':
                    case 'email':
                    case 'hidden':
                    case 'password':
                    case 'button':
                    case 'reset':
                    case 'submit':
                        q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
                        break;
                    case 'checkbox':
                    case 'radio':
                        if (form.elements[i].checked) {
                                q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
                        }                                               
                        break;
                }
                break;
                case 'file':
                break; 
            case 'TEXTAREA':
                    q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
                    break;
            case 'SELECT':
                switch (form.elements[i].type) {
                    case 'select-one':
                        q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
                        break;
                    case 'select-multiple':
                        for (j = form.elements[i].options.length - 1; j >= 0; j = j - 1) {
                            if (form.elements[i].options[j].selected) {
                                    q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].options[j].value));
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'BUTTON':
                switch (form.elements[i].type) {
                    case 'reset':
                    case 'submit':
                    case 'button':
                        q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    return q.join("&");
}
```

Esto esta descrito en el siguiente post del sitio en ingles:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11661219/4717133

el otro método seria utilizar una Librería (no framework de terceros):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11661214/4717133 
https://code.google.com/archive/p/form-serialize/

**De cualquiera forma al final tendrías un array que puede ser fácilmente enviado en conjunto con tus datos del formulario al backend.**